# how I can use my defined method in a dataset?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've created a dataset named `DataSet1.xsd`, I've added some tables, finally I defined a method to one of these tables. (`InsertQuery(...)`)
screen shot looks like:
[image]

Now my question is how I can use this method/function in a **.aspx** page?
for example once a button pressed I want to add a row to the Person table, what i should write in button_clicked procedture?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I can solve the problem :)

```
DataSet1TableAdapters.PersonTableAdapter adapter = new DataSet1TableAdapters.PersonTableAdapter;
adapter.InsertQuery(...) // <-- my method haha!
```